# Is this grammar structure "is at its level" correct?

Tags: grammar

Can anybody explain for me how this structure "is at its highest level" is correct.
Example : **Confidence in the British economy *is at its highest level* since the Coalition came to power amid signs the recovery is gathering pace**

Comment: Note that there is no apostrophe in "its" when it is possessive. You've got it correct in your quotation, but I've corrected it in the title. And by "correction" I've assumed you mean "correct".

Comment: That's OK. But you should have said "Thanks for your *correction*". Something is (or is not) *correct*, but you make a *correction*. *Correct* is a verb; *correction* is a noun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that:

> [The] confidence [of people] [in the British economy] is at its highest level since [date/time] [because there are] signs [that] the recovery is gathering pace.

It's the **confidence** that "is at its highest level".

The word "level" is actually superfluous (unnecessary), because you could say "confidence is at its highest since ..."

It means that the confidence that people (e.g. bankers) have in the British economy is now higher than it has been at any time since the Coalition Government came to power.  And that this confidence is happening while (or even because) there are now signs (indications) that the rate at which the economy is recovering is "gathering pace"   (increasing).

Comment: Please up-vote answers if they are useful. You can up-vote several answers, but accept only one answer.

Comment: This is the first time i ask in this website, Its so amazing :D Really useful . Thanks for your guidance

Comment: You might also find the sister website [ell.se] useful.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the sentence, "level" is used to describe the amount of confidence in the British economy. A statement you may be more familiar with is "a high level of confidence in his technical abilities." Essentially, imagine confidence on a scale where a low level implies not much confidence and a high level suggests a lot of confidence.